# Terraform destroying an existing resource in GCP

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to automate the config in GCP using Terraform. There is a VPC network which is already existing and that was created manually from GCP console. I have imported the networks into the terraform state file but when i run the terraform script it is trying to destroy the network. I don't think so this is correct as i have the same config in state file as well as in the main.tf file. How do i fix this?

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_compute_network" "terraform_network" {
    auto_create_subnetworks         = false
    delete_default_routes_on_create = false
    enable_ula_internal_ipv6        = false
    mtu                             = 1460
    name                            = "terraform-network"
    project                         = "testterra-20088"
    routing_mode                    = "REGIONAL"
    timeouts {}
}
```

**Plan output**

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.entire-tf-output-projects-testterra-20088-ComputeNetwork.google_compute_network.terraform_network will be destroyed
  # (because google_compute_network.terraform_network is not in configuration)
  - resource "google_compute_network" "terraform_network" {
      - auto_create_subnetworks         = false -> null
      - delete_default_routes_on_create = false -> null
      - enable_ula_internal_ipv6        = false -> null
      - id                              = "projects/testterra-20088/global/networks/terraform-network" -> null
      - mtu                             = 1460 -> null
      - name                            = "terraform-network" -> null
      - project                         = "testterra-20088" -> null
      - routing_mode                    = "REGIONAL" -> null
      - self_link                       = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testterra-20088/global/networks/terraform-network" -> null

      - timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: We need to see the plan output for this resource.

Comment: Also: it's **never** a good idea to post a state file in a public forum.

Comment: @MarkoE I have removed it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have updated the Plan output

Comment: According to the question you imported this resource. According to the plan (and the state you deleted) you did not import this resource. Now we need to see the `terraform import` command you executed.

Comment: @MattSchuchard this is the command i have used to import. **terraform import google_compute_network.terraform_network projects/testterra-20088/global/networks/terraform-network"**

Comment: @MattSchuchard When i try to run the import command again, i am getting below message
**Error: Resource already managed by Terraform
│ 
│ Terraform is already managing a remote object for google_compute_network.terraform_network. To import to this address you must first remove the existing object from the state.**